# Doctrine MappingDriverChain error after upgrading Symfony from 3.4 to 4

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Currently I'm in the process of upgrading our project from Symfony 3.4 to Symfony 4.4.
I've already removed all the deprecations and started with upgrading the packages.

However, everything went fine with the upgrade until I encountered the following error, after I refreshed my webpage:
[image: Doctrine Error]

I've searched for several solutions on StackOverflow & Github in order to tackle this without any success. For example, I've read that `doctrine/persistence` and `doctrine/common` are split now, so it makes sense that this error occurs.

So, I've tried to downgrade `doctrine/common` to version `^2.11`, but that produces an internal server error, from which I cannot find any logs in the `var/logs` directory.

This is the composer.json which produces the MappingDriverChain error:

```
  "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
  "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
  "config": {
    "platform": {
      "php": "7.2.19"
    }
  },
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.2",
    "symfony/symfony": "^4.0",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.10",
    "twig/extensions": "^1.5",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.2",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "liip/imagine-bundle": "^2.6",
    "slot/mandrill-bundle": "1.0.10",
    "mollie/mollie-api-php": "^2.0",
    "facebook/graph-sdk": "~5.0",
    "google/apiclient": "^2.0",
    "kraken-io/kraken-php": "^1.6",
    "intervention/image": "^2.4",
    "phpseclib/phpseclib": "^2",
    "maxcdn/php-maxcdn": "2.*",
    "leaseweb/memcache-bundle": "^2.1",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php-symfony": "^2.0",
    "mongodb/mongodb": "1.0.5",
    "eko/feedbundle": "^1.2",
    "nesbot/carbon": "2.22.3",
    "php-http/message": "^1.5",
    "php-http/curl-client": "^1.7",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "eightpoints/guzzle-bundle": "^7.5",
    "guzzlehttp/psr7": "^1.5",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.87",
    "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^1.1",
    "endroid/qr-code": "^2.5",
    "embed/embed": "^3.3",
    "twilio/sdk": "^5.0",
    "giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php": "~8.0",
    "ezyang/htmlpurifier": "*",
    "voku/anti-xss": "^4.1",
    "league/csv": "^9.1",
    "suncat/mobile-detect-bundle": "^1.1",
    "ext-dom": "20031129",
    "sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser": "^1.5",
    "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.6",
    "ext-gd": "^7.1",
    "ext-mongodb": "^1.1.0",
    "mervick/emojionearea": "^3.0.0",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.13",
    "symfony/stopwatch": "^4.0",
    "exercise/htmlpurifier-bundle": "^3.0",
    "dzango/twig-truncate-extension": "^1.1",
    "dzango/twig-truncate-bundle": "^1.0",
    "ext-mbstring": "^7.2",
    "ext-exif": "^7.2",
    "ext-imagick": "*"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
    ]
  },
  "extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-var-dir": "var",
    "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
    "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
      "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
      "dev-master": "5.11-dev"
    }
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
      "OP_": "src/"
    },
    "psr-4": {
      "": "src/"
    },
    "files": [
      "app/AppKernel.php"
    ]
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "type": "project",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

What could be the cause of this error and what would be the solution to it in order to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried removing the cache dir and rebuilding it with the updated code?

Comment: @dbrumann Yes just did that, rebuilded everything, but still produces that error page.

Comment: The configuration is set up using the `doctrine/doctrine-bundle`, so you could try upgrading it.

Comment: @dbrumann Alright, updated to ```doctrine/doctrine-bundle: "^2.4"``` after a refresh it displayed an error about a ```DoctrineCacheBundle```. So I've removed that from the AppKernel. Next on, after refreshing again it produced the error ```The service alias "doctrine.orm.default_metadata_cache" does not exist.```

Comment: You probably need to update your cache configuration. You can use the recipe as a reference: https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/2.4/config/packages/prod/doctrine.yaml

Comment: @dbrumann Thanks that should be it!